# Assigning labels to database results

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I've been meaning to ask this question for quite some time, but I couldn't (and haven't still) come up with a proper title to describe the problem. English isn't my native language, and I don't even know what this concept is called. Bear with me...

Until recently, when fetching results from a database I just had to output them the way they were stored. So when I did

`SELECT name, gender, country FROM contacts`

I just had to output it with

`echo $result['name'] . " - " . $result['gender'] . " - " . $result['country'];`.

Country names are stored in the database by their **ISO** country code. This means United States is stored as USA, and Brazil is stored as BRA. The goal of this is to ensure compatibility with other systems. Users on the other hand don't want to deal with these country codes, they want to see the full country name.

Likewise, when performing a search for all the contacts of a given country, they want to be able to enter the full country name in the search box, not the **ISO-code**.

How can i assign labels (human readable values if you will) to these results?

I'm using PHP without a framework but i do follow the **MVC** analogy (separation of business logic and presentation). How would this fit in an **MVC** architecture?

Comment: Why not create a database table matching country ISO codes to their labels and then join that table when you do the query?

Answer (score 1):

Table "contacts" contains columns name, gender, country ISO code.  Table "country_labels" contains country ISO code and label.

MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts INNER JOIN country_labels ON contacts.country=country_labels.country
```

PHP:

```
echo $result['name'] . " - " . $result['gender'] . " - " . $result['label'];.
```